# How to add a class to a html element through a ViewBag property?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So if I have a view that gets a model that hasn't anything to do with the html element  I want to add a certain class to, how do I do this? I presume I have to use the ViewBag, but I can't figure it out.

The view ends up being like this.

```
@model CRW.WebUI.Models.ItemsListViewModel

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "ListP";
}

<h2>Discounts available</h2>

@foreach (var p in Model.Items)
{
Html.RenderPartial("ProductsListing", p);
}
```

I want to add the class attribute in this view and I don't want to associate anything with the model. I want that to remain intact.

I want to add the class "selected" on an element a that is defined in a Shared view and that I can identify by its innerHtml string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ViewBag` as below.

```
<h2 class="@(ViewBag.MyClass)">Discounts available</h2>

@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "method", "controller", null, new { @class = ViewBag.MyClass })
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is not what I want, the html element is not defined in this View, it's already loaded on the page by a Shared view.

Comment: @user3046061, The ViewBag is accessible across all views and partial views

Comment: I'm not able to stringify the ViewBag property inside the ActionLink parameter...The ViewBag gets inserted literally inside the html element.

Comment: Still doesn't work. To be clear the ViewBag property is once checked when it's non existing then it should change on click when it should have the string value in it. Since it doesn't work this means that the html doesn't load again or the ViewBag is not set correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't get it, can you please explain with a example.

Answer (score 0):

Using `?` operator to set conditional HTML class for example to hide or show simple bootstrap alert div, you can use the `new HtmlString()` function in `System.Web`:

```
<div @(ViewBag.MsgToClient == null ? new HtmlString("class=\"hidden\"") : new HtmlString("class=\"alert alert-light\"")) role="alert">
        <h4>Validation Error:</h4>
        <h5 class="text-danger">@ViewBag.MsgToClient</h5>
</div>
```